# Cannot bind to controller without directive 'tabset's controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular, and I'm facing some problem while making the directives to communicate, getting **Cannot bind to controller without directive 'tabset's controller**
Here is my [Code](https://jsfiddle.net/6ydm26pb/)

```
HTML code
```

```html
<tabset>
 <tab heading="Tab 1">
  Hi
 </tab>
 <tab heading="Tab 2">
  Second tab 
 </tab> 
</tabset>
```

Directive for the above code

```js
angular.module('testApp')
.directive('tab', function(){
 return{
  restrict: 'E',  
  transclude: true,
  template: '<h1>Hello Developer!!</h1><div role="tabpanel"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>',
  require: '^tabset',
  scope: {
   heading: '@'
  },
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs, tabsetCtrl){
   tabsetCtrl.addTab(scope);

  }
 }
}).directive('tabset', function(){ 
 return{
  restrict: 'E',  
  transclude: true,
  scope: { },
  templateUrl: 'views/tabset.html',
  bindToController: true,  
  controllerAs: 'tabset',
  contrller: function(){
   var self = this;
   this.tabs = [];

   self.addTab = function addTab(tab)
   {
    self.tabs.push(tab);
   }
  }

 }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening because you spelled "controller" wrong. Under controllerAs, you have "contrller"